# Removing Special Char from file names in powershell

Tags: powershell

So I am currently in the middle of try to migrate a massive amount of end user files from NTFS to MS OneDrive.  The problem I am facing is that OneDrive does not support special characters in file names and these files are riddled with them.

So the idea is to copy the file and folder structure to a new destination and run a PS script to rename them all and remove all the special chars from them.

`Get-childobject -recurse` seams to be the best option here.

I can rename a single file using something along the lines of:

```
$newname = $oldname.replace ("&"," and ")
$newname = $newname.replace (" & "," and ")
$newname = $newname.replace ("/"," ")
#etc...
```

However I am not certain as to how I would either pipe or bracket these together and if it is even possible?

Or is there something I have overlooked that is far simpler?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: _Get-childobject -recurse seams to be the best option here_ As soon as you haven't installed any extending modules, there is no `Get-ChildObject`. Also, NTFS doesn't support `/` in file names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To wrap multiple replace operations together, one can either wrap `[String]`'s [`Replace()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace(v=vs.110).aspx) method like:

```
$newName = $oldName.Replace("&", "and").Replace("_", "-") #etc.
```

or use PowerShells builtin [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-5.1#replacement-operator) operator:

```
$newName = $oldname -replace "&", "and" -replace "_", "-" #etc.
```

To generally fit Strings into conventions there are methods like `[uri]::EscapeDataString()`. I'm not sure about OneDrive and their file name conventions, but could imagine they have to be convertable to internet URLs.

---

To make it more readable one could build a [`HashTable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables?view=powershell-5.1) like the following:

```
$replacements = @{
    "&" = "and";
    "_" = "-";
    "/" = "-";
}
$fileName = "Actually/IsSupportedByNeitherNTFSNorOneDrive"
$replacements.Keys | ForEach-Object {$fileName = $fileName.replace($_, $replacements[$_])}
Write-Output $fileName
#Actually-IsSupportedByNeitherNTFSNorOneDriveandsomeOthers
```